# Text Input to Spiking Neural Networks

Tags: deep-learning

I'm working on a Project that requires me to give text as input to a Spiking Neural Network. Can anyone provide me with any pointers/ references to materials that talk about doing so? 
Can Word embeddings be used to provide such input? 
I've been searching a lot but coming up with nothing. Maybe I'm yet to look at the right places?

Comment: If I am right you might be having problem with when to change a value and when not to change a value in SNN, checkout RNN's with LSTM that should help, based on your proficiency in deep learning either checkout the video or view the full playlist upto that video, if you still need help, add comments accordingly. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wh4HWWfZIY&index=10&list=PL1w8k37X_6L_s4ncq-swTBvKDWnRSrinI

Comment: Although even after all that you might not be able to implement it properly as explained here https://towardsdatascience.com/spiking-neural-networks-the-next-generation-of-machine-learning-84e167f4eb2b

Comment: If it is a school project RNN with LSTM will work, If not you will have to come up with a training mechanism on your own (Not as easy as it sounds) and implement it in lower level frameworks like numpy or tensorflow.

Comment: Hey thanks anand_v.singh ! No, its a college project and I have to use SNN's. There are multiple instances of Images as input to SNN's but not text. Hence, the frustration. Even if i pre process the text and get its word embeddings, i'm not sure how to convert these embeddings into spikes.

Comment: That is still actively under research and I don't think you would be able to find that, I think you might be able to use similarity index to map it into spikes, I am not sure though, sorry couldn't be of more help.